# How to make vimgrep do word match search?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I have below statement in _vimrc file to map F3 to do vimgrep for word under current cursor.

```
map <F3> :execute "noautocmd vimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/gj **/*." .  expand("%:e") <Bar> cw<CR>
```

Now, I want to make it vimgrep for exact word match for word under current cursor. I changed it as below but it doesn't work.

```
map <leader>s :execute "noautocmd vimgrep /\<" . expand("<cword>") . "\>/gj **/*." .  expand("%:e") <Bar> cw<CR>
```

Anything is wrong? How can i achieve exact word match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to double up the backslashes - a single backslash will escape the next character, and if the character does not have a special meaning then the backslash is removed.  e.g.

```
echo "\<"
```

will print

```
<
```

This seems to work OK:

```
map <leader>s :execute "noautocmd vimgrep /\\<" . expand("<cword>") . "\\>/gj **/*." .  expand("%:e") <Bar> cw<CR>
```